# Difference between return and => (fat arrow)

Tags: dart

AFAIK, these two code are doing the same thing:

```dart
Future<int> f1() async {
  return 0;
}

Future<int> f2() async => 0;
```

But when I use the following, I only get the error in `f1`.

```
Future<void> f1() async {
  return Exception(); // Error
}

Future<void> f2() async => Exception();
```

Why they are behaving differently?

Comment: What is the error you're seeing and what are you intending to do? I'm pretty sure the code is the same, but I don't think either is valid because you're returning Exception (I don't know if you intended to `throw`?) from functions that declare that they return `void`.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny Error: `A value of type 'Exception' can't be returned from the function 'f1' because it has a return type of 'Future<void>'.` I know it should actually use `throw` for an Exception but I was just playing around.

Comment: Ah, got it. I think what's happening is that the lambda is allowed to ignore the return value (because the declared return type is a `void`) so that you can use expressions that don't return (eg. you could do `void foo() => _foo = bar`), but I don't think that's the case for an explicit `return`. I can't find docs about this though..

Comment: @DannyTuppeny So, this is the answer to my question `lambda is allowed to ignore the return value`. Can you please write it down and do you also have some docs link for this?

Comment: I found the relevant part of the spec and posted it in an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For lambdas, when the return type of the function is `void`, the expressions return type is allowed to not match. That's not the case for an explicit return.

This is described in the spec here:

https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf

From page 19:

> In particular, `e` can have any type when the return
> type is `void`. This enables concise declarations of `void` functions. It
> is reasonably easy to understand such a function, because the return
> type is textually near to the returned expression `e`. In contrast, `return e;` in a block body is only allowed for an `e` with one of a few specific
> static types, because it is less likely that the developer understands
> that the returned value will not be used (17.12).

That's for synchronous functions, but for async it also states:

> In particular, `e` can
> have any type when the *flattened* return type is `void`, and the rationale
> is similar to the synchronous case.

Comment: You was seconds faster than me to convert that text from the PDF. My reader really destroyed the formatting :D

Comment: @julemand101 hehe, I saw your answer appear right after I posted. I had to fix the formatting too - I wonder if there's a mackdown version of that spec on GH somewhere!

Comment: Unfortunately no since it is a big LaTeX file which is not easier to copy from :D: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/specification/dartLangSpec.tex